# Are Product Codes on installed Windows Programs identical on all computers? Or does each computer assign one at random?

Tags: windows, batch-file, guid, windows-installer

All of the research I have done into this subject on my own seems to claim that each installed program is assigned a GUID that is unique. With that in mind, I set out to design a very simple .bat file that would silently uninstall a set list of programs using msiexec

Using MSI Inventory (which is similar to getting the GUID from registry under HKLM), I gathered all of the Product Codes for each program I wanted to uninstall.

Example:

```
Product code:   {89C254A9-2FB5-4FC9-B34F-BDEB2713C5FA}
Product state:  (5) Installed.
Package code:   {BD709EB5-2B9C-4664-A654-C9AB18B25DBE}
Version:    2.10.28
```

I took the PRODUCT CODE from the above example and wrote my batch very simply with:

```
msiexec /x {89C254A9-2FB5-4FC9-B34F-BDEB2713C5FA} /passive
```

As I understood it, this ID : {89C254A9-2FB5-4FC9-B34F-BDEB2713C5FA} should be unique to this program that I am uninstalling. So if I run this batch from another computer with the same program installed, it will find it and uninstall it passively without user required input.

However, I am having mixed results. Some computers it uninstalls from, some it doesn't seem to find the program. MSI Inventory on the computers that fail to uninstall the program show different product codes.

I am wondering, are these product codes TRULY unique GUIDs that are created at the time of program creation and embedded in the installer? Should they be the same on every machine you install the program on?

If the answer is yes, I must be dealing with a "different version" issue where the program code changed over time... but I need to know for sure before I put too much work into a .bat file that may only work -some- times.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure the programs on different computers are all the exact same version?

Answer (score 2):

The GUID varies from diffent versions and languages of the installed application.
You should first ensure that these are identical before attempting to unistall them with this batch file. There are better ways of doing this than using a batch file though.

If you know C/C++ consider the MSDN documentation on using the Windows Installer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372463%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), especially the [*Determining Installation Context*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) section.

Answer (score 1):

The [product code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/6fbad59b-27b7-4ac1-bad5-8a608c7b270f) is a GUID that is considered the *principal identification* of an application or product.  It is a "Windows Installer Best Practice" to [Keep package names and package codes consistent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/ff48d995-fe6f-4d1b-898d-67574ed3c5b7#codes_consistent). Certain types of updates require that product code be changed. These are described in the MSDN documentation: [Changing the Product Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/4de84885-587d-405f-ba85-d62e09e8ba92).

It is therefore possible for a product to have multiple product codes.

The product code is the value of the [ProductCode property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/En-US/Library/Windows/Desktop/33cedd37-0343-471c-ad4b-0db5f98d5894) .  Different products should never be assigned the identical product code guid used by any other product.  This would be a very bad thing to do, however there is no mechanism to prevent it. The package author is responsible for using a utility such as GUIDGEN to get a unique GUID. (Note that: Utilities such as GUIDGEN can generate GUIDs containing lowercase letters. These must all be changed to uppercase letters before the GUID can be used by the installer as a valid product code.)

Comment: BTW, both answers from Mark and Arthur are correct. The ProductCode is never changed by Windows, but the level of "product" which the user is seeing, is a completely different from the ProductCode level: One user product may consist of many MSIs with different ProductCodes, and each version and/or variant of these has an own ProductCode (needed to be) assigned by their setup developer. So the ProductCode is more a unique id for one MSI file in one specific major version, and can or cannot be on the real (user) product level.